# Что находится в итераторе, который сконструирован при помощи конструктора по умолчанию?

Tags: c++, итераторы, конструктор, default

Скажите, пожалуйста, что находится в стандартном итераторе, если он получен не из контейнера, а сконструирован отдельно при помощи конструктора по умолчанию?

Например, так:

```
std::list<float>::iterator it{};
```

Comment: Нулевой указатель. Но зависит от реализации, конечно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ничего.
В глобально-философском смысле :) - потому что такой итератор вы не можете использовать без того, чтоб нарваться на UB. Разыменовывать нельзя, сравнивать нельзя...

А если некоторой вещью пользоваться нельзя - то какая разница, как она внутри устроена? :)

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Позанудствую: такие итераторы можно сравнивать с другими такими же итераторами, и [они будут равны](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator#Singular_iterators). С нормальньно сконструированными итераторами похоже сравнивать нельзя, да.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, спасибо за столь тонкое замечание.